# if statement failure(no errors) in checking to see if two hash variables are equal

Tags: php, mysqli, get

I am trying to register a user by checking if the variable in the dynamic link I sent them by email matches the hash value that is stored in mysql.

I tried debugging this. I found that $verify and $hash are indeed equal when echoed out into the browser just before my if statement.
   One hash value comes from mysqli select query whereas the other comes from a $_GET[''] post. 
    My hash contains (=,$+) symbols. Could that be preventing it from evaluating correctly? When my code is displayed in the browser it doesn't do anything with the if statement.(I don't receive a echo of "it works" nor an echo of "it doesn't work")
    If you know what this problem might be or have advise on trouble shooting it would be much appreciated. Thanks for all your help in advance.

Part of the code I seem to be having trouble with:

```
if ($verify === $hash ){
echo "It works!";}
else{ echo "It doesn't work!";}
```

I also tried evaluating it with the 2 following alternatives and they didn't work:

```
$values = array($verify, $hash);

if(count(array_unique($values)) === 1) {
echo "It works!";}


if (strcmp("$verify","$hash")===0){
echo "It works!";
```

Here is my complete code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$un = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "secure_login";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $un, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['username']);
$hash = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['hash']);

$sql = "SELECT hash FROM login WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $verify = $row["hash"];
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
echo "Error Selecting record: " . $conn->error;
}

echo $username;
echo $hash;
if ($verify == $hash ){
echo "It works!";

$sql = "UPDATE login SET active = 1 WHERE username = '$username'";
}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo  $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
```

Comment: Instead of `echo` use `var_dump`

Comment: *"My hash contains (=,$+) symbols."* - `$hash = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['hash']);` that's a problem.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how hashing passwords works, I dont see password_verify anywhere?

Comment: Nor SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you. mysqli_real_escape_string() removed. Now I just have a "+" missing from my $_GET['hash'] variable(which came from my dynamic url), it was replaced with a space. What could be removing it? or how do I get around that?

Comment: How can I used password_verify if I don't have access to the user's password to check it against the hash. I thought this was the whole point of security with hashing... only the user knows their own password and it isn't stored on the database.